# How to create a development SaaS offer

Tags: saas, marketplace

Per the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/marketplace/plan-saas-dev-test-offer I would like to create a DEV offer to build and test the technical aspects of the SaaS offer like the landingpage, webhook, connection to the fulfillment API, etc. This sounds great, but unfortunately that page doesn't explain how I am supposed to do that.

I've created a SaaS offer that is intended to be my DEV offer on https://partner.microsoft.com/ but all I can do is submit the offer for review and subsequent publication. I understand that after validation I have the opportunity to test the offer but it seems I have to provide a more or less finished offer because other it will be rejected.
So what is the approach for creating the DEV SaaS offer?